# mysqldump with multiple tables with where clause thowing an error code (1054)

Tags: mysql

I want to dump data from multipe tables for a specific time period.

So I added a WHERE clause for each table to the dump command. I used the following command:

`` mysqldump -uroot -proot database_name medical_voucher --where="voucher_date between '2019-06-24' and CURDATE()" rawdata --where="`date` between '2019-06-24' and CURDATE()"> d:\test4.sql ``

I am getting following error

`` mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `medical_voucher` WHERE `date` between '2019-06-24' and CURDATE()': Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause' (1054) ``

So please advise what is wrong here. My sqldump command is not working correctly as it ?

Comment: Try: set the column name date in backticks. date is a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: @BerndBuffen tried setting date in backticks, but same error

Comment: Can you show the table definition? The first thing to confirm is that there's actually a column exactly named `date`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `rawdata` (
  `BRNO` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TYPE` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE1` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLAG` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MCODE` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAMOUNT` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAX` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIAB` char(1) DEFAULT '',
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `CODE` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @jerry there is a column named DATE

Comment: @spt - where is the create from **medical_voucher** ??

Comment: CREATE TABLE `medical_voucher` (
  `BRNO` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `MCODE` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BRANCH` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAMOUNT` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAX` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAMOUNT1` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `VOUCHER_NO` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VOUCHER_SNO` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VOUCHER_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCODE` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESIGNATION` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BKCD` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL)

Comment: @BerndBuffen medical_voucher table defination

Comment: The `medical_voucher` table does not have a column named `date`. It has a column named `voucher_date`.

Comment: @BillKarwin the sqldump command is not working correctly as it, pls advise

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. You expect that you can specify a different `--where` option for each table, and name different columns.

That's not the way mysqldump works.

You can specify *one* condition with the `--where` option, and that same condition is used verbatim for *all* the tables it dumps.

So you better use a condition that is valid for all tables. Do not name columns that exist only in some of the tables.

To do what you want to do, you cannot use mysqldump. You will either have to run mysqldump multiple times (with the risk that if data changes in between these commands, you'll get inconsistent data), or else implement your own tool.